# Smooth Scrolling from CSSTricks stopped working after adding a SequenceJS slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm creating a one-page website with that smooth scrolling effect across sections (linking to anchors).
This effect I copied from CSS Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

It was working fine until I inserted a SequenceJS slider in one of the sections (http://www.sequencejs.com/)

Now the smooth scrolling is not working anymore. Something in the SequenceJS script is probably blocking the smooth-scroll (at least in Chrome for Mountain Lion). Can anyone help me?

The website I'm creating is:
http://hammr.co/5041463/8#/index.html
You can see the scripts I used there.

thanks

Comment: You have quite a few javascript errors when looking in the console. When you minified your scripts, do they have to be done in a specific order (other than loading jQuery first)?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know anything about jquery. I didn't know js was minified, I'm using this static generator called "Hammer" that probably minifies js automatically. Do u think if I don't minify it will work?